# Seeking Guidance on Excluding Directory from General CSP

Tags: nginx, content-security-policy

Good Day. I have been working on rebuilding a CSP for a client that has insisted on a particularly restrictive configuration. `:data` and `unsafe-inline` must be ruled out and my developer advises me that a nonce or hash cannot be generated for the scripts being blocked. For this reason I am limited to trying to exclude a particular directory from the main CSP.

I have so far tried adapting this override setup from 2017:

[Override CSP header for specific location](https://serverfault.com/questions/870452/override-csp-header-for-specific-location)

When this didn't work I tried a nested location block likeso:

[Nginx location exclude specific folder](https://serverfault.com/questions/1065639/nginx-location-exclude-specific-folder)

Neither of these approaches have worked unfortunately.

I have successfully moved my `$cspheader` configuration to the map area as suggested in the initial example. I am aware that the strictest CSP will ultimately be applied to a directory with two CSPs by default without some manner of working exclusion and the If is Evil (in Location context especially) in NGINX. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Hi development question should be asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Which is funny because I got a downvote there and was told this same question didn't belong there.

Comment: but then something with your question is somthing either wrong, or not well stated.